# Django: User Javascript object as context variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have been having this problem for long. But I am not able to figure how to do this. Is there a way so, we can use the javascript objects with the template language. For example, I have queryset of categories which are rendered on a select widget.

```
Category: <select name="category" id="id_category">
{% for category in categories %}
<option value="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Now, for the selected category, I asynchronously call the server to return the related Product Types.

```
$('#id_category').change(function(){
    getProductTypes($(this).val());

});
```

In the ajax function, I am unable to use the category_id js object in the url template tag. Due to this I am bound to hard code the target url. Can anyone please suggest a way to handle this. Thanks

```
function getProductTypes(category_id){
         //Would like to do this
           var url = {% url lookup_product_types category_id %}
         //But end up doing this
           var url = '/'+category_id+'/product_types/find/'
              $.ajax({
                url:url,
                data:{category:category_id},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data, status, xhr){
                    html = '<select>';
                    $.each(data, function(index, value){
                        html += '<option value='+this.pk+'>'+this.fields.name+'</option>';
                    });
                    html += '</select>';
                    $('#productType').html(html);
                }  
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) on the option tags?

You would update your template to something like -

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <option data-url="{% url lookup_product_types category.id %}" value="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Then change the ajax along the lines of -

```
$('#id_category').change(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-url');
    getProductTypes($(this).val(), url);
});

function getProductTypes(category_id, url){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data:{ category:category_id},
        // ..
```

Comment: This seems to be a good way of doing it. Thanks I will go ahead with this.

Comment: No problem - I only came across data-attribute recently - I felt like I've been looking for it for ages!

Comment: hehe...We generally miss the obvious. Thanks again.